# How do I tell SpringBoot where to find Python packages?

Tags: python, java, spring-boot, ubuntu

I've installed several Python libraries, like the "ML" library called "flair" into Ubuntu server 20.04.

Now, although I can run the flair python program, as one example, fine **from the command line** in Ubuntu 20.04 server (Ubuntu knows where to look), when I run this same logic ($python3 + " " + program path.py +  " " + data path) from SpringBoot (a WAR file), I get the message that:

import flair

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair'
```

This Springboot approach works fine in Windows, but I'm missing something with Ubuntu.

I'm not therefore sure where SpringBoot looks for Python modules (or in general). There is no environment variable called "CLASSPATH", just path.

However, I changed the regular path variable to include the site-packages folder beneath  **/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages**, but it made no difference.

I created a CLASSPATH variable to see if that would help, but SpringBoot (the WAR file context) still doesn't find the packages in the Ubuntu path.

So, where do I need to put the Python modules, or how do I tell SpringBoot where they are now via environment variable or other method?

Thanks,

Comment: [This page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html) describes how python looks for installed packages. It seems like you need to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable for the python process being executed. Check what its value is in the shell where everything works. This should give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out where to put the modules so SpringBoot would see them in Ubuntu, but now I get: "OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/.flair'" when running the code. I can't seem to change permissions "chwon" or  "chmod" at all.

Comment: Please post the code you use to execute the python script from the Java app

Comment: Another possible reason for the error is the python script tries to write to `/.flair` directory and it does not have permission to do so. It seems like it tries to write (maybe even create) to a directory in the root of the file system which is likely prohibited. Try to set the script working directory to a non-root folder and see if it will resolve the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks Sergei! The way I'm executing the Python code inside SpringBoot is like this: "process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);" cmdArray has the python executable to use, the path to the "py" file and the path to the data file to read. I tried changing permissions, moving things around, etc., but I could never get Java to execute the python successfully. Everything worked fine at the command line. Also tried to set the PYTHONPATH in /etc/environment, but that didn't help. Do I need to use a Java "ProcesBuilder" and inject paths there? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you need 2 things: make sure that the `python` executable is available on your `PATH` and that the `PYTHONPATH` includes the location of the `flair` package so it can be imported.

It should be ok to use either `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`. I went with `ProcessBuilder` because it is more convenient to use.

Here's a code snippet that lunches a python script that imports `flair` and then prints the current working directory and `sys.path` content:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "python3", 
    "-c", 
    "import os; import sys; import flair; print(os.getcwd()); print(sys.path)"
)
    .directory(new File("/home/user/tmp/flair"))
    .inheritIO();

// I used one of the virtual envs available on my machine with flair installed
builder.environment().put("PYTHONPATH", ".venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages");

Process p = builder.start();
```

For me it prints:

```
/home/user/tmp/flair
['', '/home/user/tmp/flair/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/python@3.10/3.10.9/lib/python3.10', '/usr/local/python@3.10/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

When I remove the line that sets environment I get an error because flair cannot be found.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair'
```

See if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this will work if I use a java program and run it on Linux. Using the Java program, I can get the Flair code to work as both "ubuntu" and as "su" (the only two users I have). My PB is a little different but semantically the same. Without the ProcessBuilder, "su" will not work. However, when running this exact code in a SpringBoot Service class, I still get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flair' error. Any ideas why? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If it errors out with `ModuleNotFoundError` it means it is not able to locate the module. Try to print the value of `sys.path` in the python script to see which directories are looked up to load modules and see if flair is in one of them.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that. At the moment, for whatever reason. the SpringBoot app won't write to the application log on Ubuntu 20. The log is there, but always zero bytes. Once I figure that out, I can try your suggestion. Many thanks again.